# Should I tag with Catholicism when the question is obviously about Catholicism?

Tags: discussion, tags, catholicism

Just wondering if [this tantum ergo](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4866/whats-the-new-rite-in-tantum-ergo) question ought to be tagged with [catholicism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catholicism) on account of it's inherent Catholicity.

Obviously it doesn't hurt to put the tag on it, but the question isn't about Catholic doctrine, just about the meaning of some very oft repeated lyrics.

Answer (score 6):

Yes absolutely.

The tags serve several purposes. One of them that is relevant to this decision is that people with specific expertise can choose to follow a tag and be notified of new questions in that area only. If the question is something more likely to interest a Catholic than a Methodist or specific expertise might have a better chance of answering it, by all means tag it!